# Can't copy connectors when creating component instances in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect, component-diagram

I tried to create **component instances with the connectors** in the deployment diagram in Enterprise Architect as below:

- select all components for which I need to create the instances and connectors in the component diagram
- drag & drop them to the deployment diagram
- mark *"Copy connectors"*

But the connectors are not displayed.

EA version: 13.5.1351.

Component diagram
[image]

Deployment diagram
[image]

Thank you

Comment: EA version would be helpful. But I just smell a bug here,

Comment: The connector is between two interfaces (provided and required) rather than between instances of components. EA is copying the components' connectors -- they're between the new component instances and the interfaces??

Comment: @muszeo It should copy all connectors as the docs say. Most likely a bug.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, yes as far I know it should work. Doesn't matter if it's a component instance. The EA version is 13.5.1351.

Comment: It appears that EA does not create connectors for any structured element (port/interface). Report a bug. Don't hold your breath (except you can do that for a couple of years).